# Javascript: Is it possible to force re-render of vector graphics in 3d transformations?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, 3d

In javascript/Html5 I can zoom into a div in two ways:
- using transform:scale(n)
- using transform:translate3d(0px,0px,nnnpx)

the div Im zooming has text and svg images, but
if I use the "scale" method fonts and images are re-rendered and shown very well 
while if I use "3d" method is like the browser "freezes" the div and then magnifies it but in the original resolution, so I get text and images blurred...

is there any way to force the browser to re-render the div?

thanks

Comment: If `scale` works, why can't you use it?

Comment: i'm trying to display a div in a 3d space